# Is it safe to use Glide Caching instead of Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-glide, android-internal-storage

I have a scenario where i have to keep few images in offline mode. Now i am confused here that should i rely on **Glide's cache** or I have to put those images in **Internal Storage**?

Hopefully Glide will work, but need to know if there exists any limitation if i go with Glide. Here word **cache** is causing confusion.

Comment: Look out this article https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics

Comment: Had a look, but as i said can its caching can be used instead of Internal Storage? What confused me is word Cache.

Comment: You can do it but limitation 50MB for internal storage.

Comment: Glide provides both in memory and disk caches. A disk cache would store your images in internal memory. I wouldn't manually save images to storage until I have a very specific need for them, but as you said it's just caching for you so glide should do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the information about underlying memory usage by Glide.

> Glide uses DiskLruCacheWrapper as the default DiskCache. DiskLruCacheWrapper is a fixed size disk cache with LRU eviction. The default disk cache size is 250 MB and is placed in a specific directory in the Application’s cache folder.

Further underlying complexities of Glide are [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#disk-cache). Hope confusion about the max memory Glide uses is cleared here and if customization is needed, that can also be achieved by following the link mentioned.